# Fedora, Rails: Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.19.0'` succeeds before bundling

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, rubygems, fedora

I'm new to Linux, and I just installed a distro korora based on fedora.
I installed rails but when i try to create new project and write bundle install in the terminal i got this error

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..............
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake 12.0.0
Using concurrent-ruby 1.0.2
Using i18n 0.7.0
Using minitest 5.10.1
Using thread_safe 0.3.5
Using builder 3.2.2
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using mini_portile2 2.1.0
Using rack 2.0.1
Using nio4r 1.2.1
Using websocket-extensions 0.1.2
Using mime-types-data 3.2016.0521
Using arel 7.1.4
Using bundler 1.13.6
Using byebug 9.0.6
Using ffi 1.9.14
Using rb-fsevent 0.9.8
Using method_source 0.8.2
Installing pg 0.19.0 with native extensions
Using puma 3.6.2
Using thor 0.19.4
Using tzinfo 1.2.2
Using nokogiri 1.6.8.1
Using rack-test 0.6.3
Using sprockets 3.7.0
Using websocket-driver 0.6.4
Using mime-types 3.1
Using rb-inotify 0.9.7
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /home/myusername/.gem/ruby/gems/pg-0.19.0/ext
/usr/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20161213-11986-1jtdscv.rb extconf.rb
checking for pg_config... no
No pg_config... trying anyway. If building fails, please try again with
 --with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib64
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --with-pg
    --without-pg
    --enable-windows-cross
    --disable-windows-cross
    --with-pg-config
    --without-pg-config
    --with-pg_config
    --without-pg_config
    --with-pg-dir
    --without-pg-dir
    --with-pg-include
    --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
    --with-pg-lib
    --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/lib64

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /home/myusername/.gem/ruby/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/pg-0.19.0/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /home/myusername/.gem/ruby/gems/pg-0.19.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/myusername/.gem/ruby/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/pg-0.19.0/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing pg (0.19.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.19.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I don't know what to do and I want to solve this problem as possible as I can.

Comment: If you have further issues, please ask them as separate questions, rather than in comments to this question. Additionally, consider accepting the answer that helped you, if it solved this particular issue; http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install the development pg library first.

`yum install postgresql-devel`

or if you're using apt:

`apt-get install libpq-dev`

Then `gem install pg -v '0.19.0'`.

Comment: This step helps but I had to execute the following statement:

`gem install pg -v '1.2.3' -- --with-pg-config=/usr/pgsql-12/bin/pg_config`

Answer (score 1):

try with:

```
sudo dnf install libpq-devel
```

then:

```
gem install pg
```

or:

```
bundle install
```

it works for me with Rails 5.2 on Fedora 30